Gradle Version Catalog - set preferred version as versionRef?
I want to set the preferred version as versionRef. Is it possible?
Right now I have:
library("jacksonModuleKotlin", "com.fasterxml.jackson.module", "jackson-module-kotlin").version { prefer("2.18") }

but I would like to have something like:
library("jacksonModuleKotlin", "com.fasterxml.jackson.module", "jackson-module-kotlin").version { prefer.versionRef("jacksonKotlinModule") }

